# Motion Sensing Loop Error Python?

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, sensors, infrared

Hi Guys I have been working on this code for quite a while but once the code has sensed motion, taken a picture and sent it off as an email attachment it works once but once the state returns to ready it comes up with this error but I can't understand why. I apologise for including the whole code because although the error states line 43 I'm not to sure what's causing it to go wrong.
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner in python programming so I may be missing something very obvious. By the way I'm running this on a raspberry pi for anyone who would like to test out the code.
Thanks

```
import os, re
import sys
import smtplib
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


GPIO_PIR = 4

print "PIR Module Test (CTRL-C to exit)"


GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIR,GPIO.IN)     

Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0
cam = picamera.PiCamera()
try:

  print "Waiting for PIR to settle ..."


  while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
    Current_State  = 0

  print "  Ready"


  while True :


    Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

    if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
      print "  Motion detected!"
      cam.capture('/home/pi/Eaglecam/surveillance.jpg')
      print('picture taken')
      cam.close()
      SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
      SMTP_PORT = 587       
      sender = '*******************'
      password = "secret!!"
      recipient = '*********************'
      subject = 'INTRUDER DETECTER!!'
      message = 'INTRUDER ALLERT!! INTRUDER ALERT!! CHECK OUT THIS PICTURE OF THE INTRUDER! SAVE THIS PICTURE AS EVIDENCE!'

      directory = "/home/pi/Eaglecam/"

      def main():
          msg = MIMEMultipart()
          msg['Subject'] = 'INTRUDER ALERT'
          msg['To'] = recipient
          msg['From'] = sender

          files = os.listdir(directory)
          jpgsearch = re.compile(".jpg", re.IGNORECASE)
          files = filter(jpgsearch.search, files)
          for filename in files:
              path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
              if not os.path.isfile(path):
                  continue

              img = MIMEImage(open(path, 'rb').read(), _subtype="jpg")
              img.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
              msg.attach(img)

          part = MIMEText('text', "plain")
          part.set_payload(message)
          msg.attach(part)

          session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

          session.ehlo()
          session.starttls()
          session.ehlo
          session.login(sender, password)

          session.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
          session.quit()

      if __name__ == '__main__':   
      print('  Email Sent')
      Previous_State=1
    elif Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:

      print "  Ready"
      Previous_State=0

    time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"

  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Here is the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/hi2.py", line 43, in <module>
    cam.capture('/home/pi/Eaglecam/surveillance.jpg')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1446, in capture
    camera_port, output_port = self._get_ports(use_video_port, splitter_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 708, in _get_ports
    self._camera[0].output[self.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PORT]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: Apologies forgot to add error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not persisting your `cam` object...`picamera` flushes and closes as it sees fit so you may be having problems calling the object repeatedly with the code you are using. Also, you are calling the `.close()` method on your `cam` object after if takes the first picture. I might accomplish this like so:

```
surv_pic = open('/home/pi/Eaglecam/surveillance.jpg', 'wb')
if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
    print "  Motion detected!"
    with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
        ##if camera is not producing pictures because it is not warmed up yet uncomment the next two lines
        ##cam.start_preview()
        ##time.sleep(2)
        cam.capture(surv_pic)
    surv_pic.close()
    SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    ## continue as is from here
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but now it's come up with this error. 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/hi2.py", line 43, in <module>
    cam.capture('/home/pi/Eaglecam/surveillance.jpg')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1446, in capture
    camera_port, output_port = self._get_ports(use_video_port, splitter_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 708, in _get_ports
    self._camera[0].output[self.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PORT]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: @JamesGrogan see my edits above. This time we'll open the file for the cam object and close it ourselves. Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Did you comment out the `cam = picamera.PiCamera()` statement you had near the top?

Comment: One other thing you might be able to do is put the picture taking itself in another .py program...and then just call it as needed. Then all the resources should be fresh each time you call it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm such an idiot I was running the a old copy of the program every time we tried something different works a treat!!!✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅

Comment: @JamesGrogan Sweet. So the code in the answer works for you then, right?